# Get selected object in angular select

Tags: angularjs

I have a select that I'm populated and defaulting based on an outside value:

```
<select ng-model="course.instructor_id" ng-options="instructor.id as instructor.first_name for instructor in instructors"></select>
```

I think I need to keep the ng-model and options pretty close to this so it updates/defaults the course model correctly but I need to grab a property of the currently selected instructor object.

How do I get the currently selected object for this select?

I want to be able to show the picture of the currently selected instructor:

```
<img ng-src="selected_instructor.picture""/>
```

Comment: can you bind to `selected_instructor` directly `<select ng-model="selected_instructor" ng-options="c.first_name for c in instructors"></select>` ? or you have to bind to `course`

Comment: The issue was that I wanted to keep the model as is. I've marked what I think is the most elegant solution. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update the course model when a new instructor is selected, you can use

```
$scope.$watch
```

to watch for changes of the selected_instructor value.

Here is an example:

```
app.controller("instructorCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.course = {
    instructor_id: null
  };

  $scope.instructors = [{
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Stefano", 
    lastName: "Baroni",
    imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/300x150"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    firstName: "Elisa",
    lastName: "Molinari",
    imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/150x150"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    firstName: "Stefano",
    lastName: "De Gironcoli",
    imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/200x150"
  }]

  $scope.$watch(
    "selected_instructor",
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue === oldValue) {
        return;
      }
      $scope.course.instructor_id = newValue.id;
    }
  )
})
```

html template:

```
<div ng-controller="instructorCtrl">
  <img src="{{selected_instructor.imageUrl}}" />
  <br/>

  <select ng-model="selected_instructor" , ng-options="instructor.lastName for instructor in instructors">
    <option value="">-- choose instructor--</option>
  </select>

  <br/><label>Currently selected instructor:</label>{{selected_instructor}}

  <br/><label>Course:</label> {{ course }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen of your question, you are never setting the selected_instructor.  Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amctammany/9Xh6L/) of my solution for you.

You were basically correct in your select tag and its ng-directives.  Here's what I used for the HTML template:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <select ng-model="instructor" ng-options="teacher.lastName for teacher in instructors">
        {{teacher.lastName}}
    </select>
    <img src="{{instructor.imageUrl}}" />
</div>
```

For the Angular base, I made a dummy app and controller as such:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []);

angular.module('demoApp')
    .controller('demoCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.instructor = null;
        $scope.instructors = {
            {
                firstName: "Scott",
                lastName: "Bohle",
                courses: ["CHEM110", "CHEM222"],
                imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/300x150"
            },
            {
                firstName: "Arial",
                lastName: "Fenster",
                courses: ["CHEM180"],
                imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/150x150"

            }
        }
    });
```

Also, bonus points to anyone who can tell what University I went to... (Hint, it's the best in Canada.)